# Un équivalent de « la partie émergée (visible) de l'iceberg »

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Connaissez-vous des équivalents de cette expression qui pourraient aller dans ce contexte ?

> je me rendais compte que [la partie visible d'un phénomène] n’était que
>   la partie émergée de l’iceberg.

L’objectif est de montrer que la partie visible d’un phénomène est superficielle/négligeable en comparaison d’une autre moins visible / plus subtile.

Comment: *l'arbre qui cache la forêt ?* l'idée n'est pas exactement la même mais pour l'emploi que tu veux en faire, je pense que ça devrait marcher non ?

Answer (score 5):

- C'est la porte noire du 10 Downing Street.
- C'est regarder ce problème par le petit bout de la lorgnette.
- C'est mettre des œillères pour regarder la mer.
- C'est une souris sur un dos d'éléphant.
- C'est 'pouième' (de la taille d'un pou) [par rapport au problème à résoudre] :
  Toutes proportions gardées, c'est insignifiant.
- Un bougie pour éclairer le soleil.
- Une goutte d'eau dans l'océan.

---

*Intégration des commentaires*

- Un grain de sable dans le désert – *[Ctouw](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/10527/ctouw)*

Comment: J'ajouterai "un grain de sable dans le désert".

Answer (score 1):

Although not as spot-on as cl-r’s good suggestions in that it doesn’t necessarily imply that the hidden part/danger is greater than the visible one, the English notion of [“There’s more than meets the eye”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=There%20is%20more%20than%20meets%20the%20eye) does at least imply that there is something unseen and/or “beneath the surface” that should/must be considered.
(from *Urban Dictionary*)

Possible French translations of this notion might include:

[« Il ne faut pas se fier aux apparences »](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/more%20than%20meets%20the%20eye), which is a [French proverb](http://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/citations/citation-55597.php)
([see here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TsOVDoxPs-UC&pg=PA260&dq=iceberg+%22il+ne+faut+pas+se+fier+aux+apparences%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGota7t5vNAhUCbRQKHRdxA9QQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=iceberg%20%22il%20ne%20faut%20pas%20se%20fier%20aux%20apparences%22&f=false) for an example of this proverb’s use in connection with the tip of an iceberg)
(from *Reverso*, *Le Monde*’s Dico-Citations, and Simon LaForet/*Google Books*' respectively)

and

« [Attention!!] [Un train peut en cacher un autre](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/un%20train%20peut%20en%20cacher%20un%20autre) », which is an SNCF safety warning that has undergone what Charlotte Schapira calls [«proverbialisation»](http://www.persee.fr/doc/lgge_0458-726x_2000_num_34_139_2382) and is used figuratively in other situations where something, usually a danger, is hidden (see page 87), such as Dominique Lamari uses it [here with "l'iceberg"](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Q_dEJo8B7oC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22un+train+peut+en+cacher+un+autre%22+iceberg&source=bl&ots=hfQfeCEkpV&sig=dpby6zV--1y9g6qL1-nc8R6lOIY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilwLvNq5vNAhVHMz4KHStnCfAQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=%22un%20train%20peut%20en%20cacher%20un%20autre%22%20iceberg&f=false)
(from *Reverso*, *Persée*, and *Google Books*, respectively)